# Assign arrays to hash subkeys

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

Given an array of keys and an array of values, I can create a hash with these keys and values using `@hash{@keys} = @vals`.

However, I would like to do this for subkeys of a hash. This does not work: `$h{"key"}{@subkeys} = @vals`.

```
$ perl -MData::Dumper -le '
  @subkeys=(qw(one two));
  @vals=(1, 2);
  $hash{"key"}{@subkeys} = @vals;
  for (qw(subkeys vals)) {
    print "$_ :\n", Dumper(\@{$_})
  };
  print "hash: \n", Dumper(\%hash);'
```

What I get is:

```
subkeys :
$VAR1 = [
          'one',
          'two'
        ];

vals :
$VAR1 = [
          1,
          2
        ];

hash: 
$VAR1 = {
          'key' => {
                     '2' => 2
                   }
        };
```

If this is possible, what would be the correct syntax to get the following Dumper result:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'key' => {
                     'one' => 1,
                     'two' => 2
                   }
        };
```

It does work when using a temporary hash:

```
perl -MData::Dumper -le '@subkeys=(qw(one two)); @vals=(1, 2); @tmp{@subkeys}=@vals; $hash{"key"}={%tmp}; print Dumper(\%hash)'
```

But I suspect I'm just missing the correct syntax to get it without the `%tmp` hash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to close the hashref part in a `@{}` slice "cast".

```
@{$hash{"key"}}{@subkeys} = @vals;
```